# Find the point in this line such that the distance from $A$ is $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

My line:

$$r: (0,2,-2) + \lambda (1,-1,2)$$

The point:

$$A = (0,2,1)$$

I know that the line has equations:

$$x = \lambda \\ y = 2-\lambda\\z = -2+2\lambda$$

But when I use the distance formula from the line to the point I get:

$$\sqrt{l^2 + (2-l -2)^2 (-2+2l-1)^2} = \sqrt{3}$$

Where $l$ is not an interger, as expected in the answer. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to take an arbitrary point on the line, which is
$$(x,y,z) = (l, 2-l, -2+2l)$$
and find it's distance $d$ from $A = (0,2,1)$, which is given by
$$
d^2 = (l-0)^2 + (2-l-2)^2 + (-2+2l+1)^2.
$$
Now note that you want $d^2=3$ and the RHS simplifies to yield
$$
3 = 2l^2 + (2l-1)^2
$$
and now can you solve it?